# Tkinter hangs after using `destroy` and `quit`

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to show a login dialog and then run my main logic.

I intend for the following snippet to close the window (finish the main loop of tk) after clicking the button and just print indefinitely (it is wrapped in `while True` is in order for the whole script to continue executing, which simulates a real program logic).
But instead, the following snippet hangs the window and fails to close in macOS Ventura with Python 3.10:

```py
from time import sleep
from tkinter import Tk, Button

def quit():
    root.quit()

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit).pack()
root.mainloop()
while True:
    sleep(1)
    print("Running a program logic...")
```

I've tried to run a functional version of this code (which fails the same) and a threaded version of it (which just crashes since an NSWindow must be created on the main thread).
I just really can't wrap my head around it!

EDIT: Fully working example
EDIT 2: Clarify the intention of this code
EDIT 3: Even more minimal code

Comment: This code won't run. It's missing some global variable definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Updated with a minimal example that does the trick

Comment: You have an infinite loop in `main`, and destroying the window won't cause that loop to terminate. I can't imagine why it would work on Windows.

Comment: I don't see why this code should work and what the code is intended to be. Could you clarify?

Comment: I would expect the window to close, and the loop to continue indefinitely. Isn't this the case? What should I do different?

Comment: Added this clarification to the question. I intend for the infinite loop to happen! I just don't want the window to show...

Comment: I managed to craft an even smaller example of my intention.

Comment: You'd say that isn't the case if you press the button and have `root.destroy()` be called ?

Comment: `root.quit()` just stops the `mainloop`. After that, the `tkinter` is still open but it can't update itself because it goes in the `while True` loop.

Comment: So how can I just kill tkinter in my case? Isn’t `quit` enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from Tkinter import *
def quit():
    global root
    root.quit()

root = Tk()
while True:
    Button(root, text="Quit", command=quit).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```